# $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}P(A_i)=x \iff \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\log(P(A_i))=log(x)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-explanation, logarithms, conditional-probability

Show for a $x>0$ (and $P$ be a probability measure)

$$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}P(A_i)=x\iff \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\log(P(A_i))=log(x)$$

---

I have thought about this question for a while but I am not seeing how to show the bi-implication. What is the trick? I see that each $1 \geq P(A_i)\geq0$ since it is a probability measure.

Comment: You should say "probability measure" at the beginning.  So that we know $P(A_i)$ cannot be negative, and it makes sense to take its logarithm.  *Hint* Can you do this for a finite sum (rather than an infinite series)?

Comment: @GEdgar edited to show now. Having looked at it I can't seem to make it make sense: LHS is some number $x>0$ is equal to a finite number of measures on events multiplied $P(A_1)\cdot ... \cdot P(A_N)$. That implying the RHS of the statement would just be that $\log(P(A_1)\cdot ... \cdot P(A_N))=\log(P(A_1))+...+\log(P(A_N))$

Comment: But how does the finite translate to the infinite here?

Comment: To go from the finite to the infinite: for the LHS product to converge means that you can take some finite number of terms in the product to get arbitrarily close to x. For the RHS sum to converge means a similar thing. You can push the corresponding $\varepsilon$ terms through a logarithm to show what you need. Or, alternatively, use the continuity of the logarithm as @GEdgar suggested.

Comment: From $\log(P(A_1)\cdot ... \cdot P(A_N))=\log(P(A_1))+...+\log(P(A_N))$, take the limit as $N \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalence would be true for finite sums and products. The infinite case then follows from the continuity of the logarithm, i.e. you can interchange the limit and the $\log$.

(Note that $P(A_i)>0$ holds for all $i$ because $x>0$.)